# Open files in a new tab in gvim

Tags: windows, vim

I started using vim/gvim for windows few days ago. I use notepad++ until now but would like to start using gvim completly.

One thing i find is, on opening a file in gvim(by double clicking the file) always opens a new instance of gvim even if another gvim instance is already running. Is there any setting that i can turn on in gvim for it to open up the file in a new tab of an already running instance of gvim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can just run:

```
gvim --remote-tab-silent <file>
```

When you run:

```
gvim --remote-tab-silent <file2>
```

This will open in the same window in a new tab...

Additionally, if you installed gvim from the native windows installer, you should have a shell extension which allows you to "open in existing vim" from windows explorer.  This will actually default to opening in a new buffer rather than a new tab.  A buffer buffers can be navigated between by doing ":bn" (buffer next) or ":bp" (buffer previous).  Personally I prefer them to tabs.

Answer (score 2):

since you mentioned notepad++, I assume that you are using vim on windows. then try this out, see if it works for you.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Launch_files_in_new_tabs_under_Windows

Answer (score 0):

I see the accepted answer gives a way to achieve the target via command line. In case you want to double click a file to open it in a new tab of the existing gvim/macvim window. Try to select "open files from applications -> in the current window -> with a tab for each file" in the preference panel of gvim/macvim.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find the right place of "open files from applications", can you show some pictures?